# Is there a way to implement Google places autocomplete in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, autocomplete, flutter-layout, google-places-autocomplete

I'm using Flutter for the first time in order to build a mobile application and I found no way to implement autocomplete google places in a textEdit component. I aim to obtain a kind of list view while the user is typing the location, as we can do in Android/iOS native implementation and react/ionic.

What I did obtain is a TextEdit component that searches possible locations and take the first one at the end. Here a snippet of my code

```
class HomeFragmentState extends State<HomeFragment>{

  GoogleMapController mapController;
  String searchAddr;
  List<Marker> markersList = [];
  Marker finalMarker;
  LatLng _center = LatLng(45.4654219,9.1859243);  // default location

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: _center,
              zoom: 11.0,
            ),
            markers: Set.from(markersList),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 10.0,
            right: 15.0,
            left: 15.0,
            child: Container(
                  height: 50.0,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      color: Colors.white
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Enter the place',
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0,top:15.0),
                            suffixIcon: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                              onPressed: searchAndNavigate,
                              iconSize: 30.0,
                            )
                        ),
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          setState(() {
                            searchAddr = val;
                          });
                        },
                        onEditingComplete: searchAndNavigate,
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void searchAndNavigate(){
    Geolocator().placemarkFromAddress(searchAddr).then((result) => {navigateTo(result:result)});
  }


  navigateTo({result, init: false}){
    var zoom = 11.0;
    var target;
    if(init){
      zoom = 12.0; //difference between searching and initializing
      target = LatLng(result.latitude, result.longitude);
    } else {
      target = LatLng(result[0].position.latitude,result[0].position.longitude);
    }
    mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
        target:target,
        zoom: zoom
    )));
  }

  void onMapCreated(controller){
    setState(() {
      mapController = controller;
      Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high).then((position) => {
        navigateTo(result: position,init: true)
      });
    });
  }


}
```

As we can see from Geolocator we can retrieve some location based on the address we're typing (hence we can take the results from there) but I didn't find a smart way to implement the part of textedit suggestions

Comment: Hope this will helps https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-places-location-search-with-map-view-using-flutter-1-0-alfian-losari-66cacb3bcc24

Comment: I have written a simple utility class to achieve this: https://arkapp.medium.com/flutter-and-google-map-for-beginners-part-1-fdba4ab22148

Answer (score 11):

I have same issue with you. actually google autocomplete can be done by basic HTTP API request. I have create some article on it called "Your Own - Flutter Google Places Autocomplete.

I have done this by basic async HTTP Request.
First you must set a controller and put listener at initialization for your TextField

```
TextField(
  controller: _controller,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Seek your location here",
    focusColor: Colors.white,
    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.map),
    suffixIcon: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
    ),
  ),
),
```

The `_controller` should be like this:

```
var _controller = TextEditingController();
```

And you must register a listener at your `initState()`

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller.addListener(() {
    _onChanged();
  });
}
```

`_onChange` function can you define as an asynchronous function to call the standard API request for `Google Places Autocomplete` that provided by Google

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?
```

please refer to this [link](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) for better understanding about the Google Place Autocomplete.

Don't forget to add [session token](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/session-tokens) so your billing will secure :)

> `sessiontoken` — A random string which identifies an autocomplete
> session for billing purposes. If this parameter is omitted from an
> autocomplete request, the request is billed independently. See the
> pricing sheet for details.

And for the last, here is the complete code for `_onChange` function:

```
_onChanged() {
  if (_sessionToken == null) {
    setState(() {
      _sessionToken = uuid.v4();
    });
  }
  getSuggestion(_controller.text);
}

void getSuggestion(String input) async {
  String kPLACES_API_KEY = "CHANGE THIS WITH YOUR GOOGLE API KEY";
  String type = '(regions)';
  String baseURL =
      'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json';
  String request =
      '$baseURL?input=$input&key=$kPLACES_API_KEY&sessiontoken=$_sessionToken';
  var response = await http.get(request);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    setState(() {
      _placeList = json.decode(response.body)['predictions'];
    });
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load predictions');
  }
}
```

your must declare `List<dynamic> _placeList = [];` at initial of Widget.

and the bonus, how we displaying the `List` of suggestion is like this:

```
ListView.builder(
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: _placeList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(_placeList[index]["description"]),
    );
  },
),
```

put this under your TextField widget.

for grab working code please refer this github link below (add the package by your own!):

https://github.com/cmailoa/google_places_autocomplete

for further explanation please check the link bellow.

https://link.medium.com/7fq2hr2WZ9

Comment: Thank you so much! Btw, how can I get the session token?!

Comment: @GIHYUNNAM As i know you just create a random character that comply to UUID standard for that. In the answers was written `_sessionToken = uuid.v4();` to generate uuid for your session.

Comment: Since the API gets called on each letter typed, won't this eat up the autocomplete api request limit? Or rather get VERY expensive as the app scales?

Comment: @JoseTapizquent yes you are right, so google provide a session. This will charged us for every ended sessions, not for each typed letter. Except you didn't create the sessions, then you will be charged very expensive :)

As you noticed, at below query example from google docs, the end lines contain "sessiontoken"

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=1600+Amphitheatre&key=<API_KEY>&sessiontoken=1234567890

Answer (score 0):

**Google places autocomplete widgets for flutter.**

---

- **dependencies** :
  flutter:
  sdk: flutter
  **flutter_google_places_hoc081098: ^1.0.0-nullsafety.4**

---

```
Future<void> _handlePressButton() async {
// show input autocomplete with selected mode
// then get the Prediction selected
Prediction? prediction = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
    context: context,
    apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
    onError: onError,
    mode: Mode.fullscreen,
  // Mode.overlay
  //language: "en",
  //components: [Component(Component.country, "in")]
);

    displayPrediction(prediction);
 }



 void onError(PlacesAutocompleteResponse response) {
homeScaffoldKey.currentState!.showSnackBar(
  SnackBar(content: Text(response.errorMessage!)),
);}
```

[Fore more information...](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_places_hoc081098)

Answer (score 0):

Please use onChanged instead of listener.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).